# Which to use :foo and foo:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the difference between these two?

- `render plain: params[:article].inspect`
- `render :plain params[:article].inspect`

For the second statement, a syntax error occurred. What's wrong with this?

Besides, I experimented

- render plain: params[article:].inspect`.

Using `params[article:]` here will lead to a syntax error. Why do we have to use `params[:article]` instead of `params[article:]` here?

Comment: You wrote that for the second statement (which uses `:plain`), an error occurs. Then you say that using `plain:` (the first expression) leads to a syntax error. Which?

Comment: `render :plain params[:article].inspect` and `render plain: params[article:].inspect` lead to errors.

Comment: `render plain: params[article:].inspect` is nowhere in your example.

Comment: My original description had problem. Edited a new one.

Comment: there are various ways to render, the simplest being `render :symbol`.  You're trying for the `render key: stringvalue` syntax.  See 2.2.5 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: @icy The definition of `render is render(options = {}, locals = {}, &block)`. Why we can use `render :symbol`? I think symbol alone is not a hash. Off the topic though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby hash syntax is `key => value`, where key can be any (almost) object, ex:

```
'my_key' => 1
:my_key => 2
```

'my_key' is a String. :my_key is a Symbol. The Symbol syntax is to put the colon *before*.

And the 'colon after symbol' syntax - `symbol: object` - is a **syntactic sugar** for `:symbol => object`. It means that this line:

```
:my_key => 2
```

is exactly the same as:

```
my_key: 2
```

You can read about it in my article [Ruby for Admins: Hashes](http://rubyforadmins.com/hashes#symbols-as-hashes-keys)

Comment: Good link. I think I can understand why I have to use `params[:article]` instead of `params[article:]` because `:article` is a key, which is also a symbol. But why using `render plain:` instead of `render :plain` here. Shouldn't we pass a symbol of an option to `render`?

Comment: `render plain: 'whatever'` means you run `render` method passing the hash with one pair: `:plain => 'whatever'`

Comment: I got it. `render plain: params[:article].inspect` should be see as `render :plain => params[:article].inspect`. `:plain` and `:article` are symbols and `:plain => params[:article].inspect` is a hash.

Answer (score 1):

The `plain:` usage is valid shortcut for symbols when you're declaring a literal hash starting on Ruby 1.9, as in:

```
some_method(class: MyClass, name: 'register-me')
```

It's also valid when declaring **named parameters** which is new to Ruby 2.1. You would do it like this:

```
def some_method( key: 'some key' )
end
```

And then call it like this:

```
some_method # assumes default value
some_method(key: "another key")
```

For all other cases, symbols are still declared as `:some_name` and you will have to declare them like this.

Comment: Named parameters is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your second sentence isn't working is because you are missing a `=>`:

```
render :plain => params[:article].inspect
```

So these two are equivalent:

```
foo: "bar"
:foo => "bar"
```

Comment: this doesn't explain when to use which.

Comment: If you read the full question you'll see he already found the answer on the difference, but was wondering why the second example didn't work for him.

Comment: when to use which?  Pre 1.9 you have to use the hashrocket (=>) > 1.9 you can use whichever you prefer. comes down to preference.  I still mix and match (which is probably bad)  since `foo: 'bar'` I like, but `foo: :bar` not so much so I normally do `:foo => :bar` in those cases.